# TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Good day! I'm a bit confused about what is wrong with the JS here. This is a bootstrap template and I'm trying to implement it on VueJS.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined
```

and when I used another browser the error message became:

```html
TypeError: t is undefined
```

The error is coming from the `bootstrap-progressbar`, however when I run it on plain HTML it is working perfectly without errors.

This is the list of imports and it seems that the order is right.

```js
import './js/jsmpeg.min.js'
import './vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'
import './vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js'
import './vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js'
import './vendor/slick/slick.min.js'

import './vendor/wow/wow.min.js'
import './vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js'
import './vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js'

import './vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js'
import './vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js'

import './vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js'
import './vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js'
import './vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js'
import './vendor/select2/select2.min.js'

import './js/main.js'
```

What might be the problem of this?

Comment: If you are using any normal builder, such as webpack, you don't have to import things like this anymore. Start from organising your project a modern way and the problem will probably be resolved by itself. There is a great article about different systems of import management: https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/

Comment: @skirtle Hey thanks for the answer, I'll be reviewing that, but for these problem I managed to run the project by installing expose-loader and importing it. Thank you!

Comment: The same error.